# Sorting a dotchart with matrix input in R

Tags: r

How do you generate a grouped Cleveland dot plot (dot chart), where the data is sorted from highest to loweset in each subroup, when your input is a matrix?

For example, R has a nice built-in example of a dotchart using groups with a matrix as input:

```
dotchart(VADeaths, main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940")
```

In this particular example, the data is already sorted in each category for each of the groups (Rural Male, Rural Female, etc.). However, if it wasn't, what are the R commands to generate a plot such that the data points in each subgroup are sorted from highest to lowest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to order your data by the column names, as @DWin suggested, but solely on numeric data, you might try:

```
# get data
data <- VADeaths[sample(1:5), ]
# order data by first row's numeric values
data <- data[order(data[,1]),]
dotchart(data)
```

Note: this will sort the dataframe by the first column only! It is not possible to sort every column in a table without specifying different rownames for each column, which is definitely not possible with table class.

**If you stick to your original question:** I would suggest splitting up the data by the columns, plot the dotchart for each sorted column and pile up those in a layout.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do the splitting and piling up?

Comment: @lorin - this should be a new question to be able to answer in deep, but in short: look after `?split` and `?par` functions. Look for `mfrow` and `mfcol` in later.

Comment: Added as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687879/splitting-the-columns-of-a-matrix-sorted-dotchart-of-each-one-then-laying-out-i

Answer (score 1):

This shows the creation of a matrix with arbitrary row order and how one can restore it to proper order.

```
> set.seed(123)
> VA2 <- VADeaths[sample(1:5), ]
> VA2
      Rural Male Rural Female Urban Male Urban Female
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
50-54       11.7          8.7       15.4          8.4
> VA2[order(rownames(VA2)), ]
      Rural Male Rural Female Urban Male Urban Female
50-54       11.7          8.7       15.4          8.4
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0
```

If you were faced with disordered colnames but not something with a the desired lexical order you could just use a character vector in the proper order with "["

```
> c2 <- c("Rural Male",   "Rural Female", "Urban Male" ,  "Urban Female")
> VA3 <- VA2[ , sample(1:4)]
> VA3
      Rural Male Rural Female Urban Male Urban Female
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
50-54       11.7          8.7       15.4          8.4
> VA3[ , c2]
      Rural Male Rural Female Urban Male Urban Female
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
50-54       11.7          8.7       15.4          8.4
```

Comment: It's not the rownames or colnames I would like sorted, what I would like is the data values ordered for each subgroup in the dotchart. I'd like the dots to be shown from largest value to smallest value for each grouping. The problem is that this can't be done simply by manipulating the matrix, because the ordering will vary from sub-group to sub-group.

Comment: Then sort by whatever is your interest. It is the ordering of the presented matrix columns and rows that determines the layout of the y-axis of dotplot.